# Undefined Method 'Match' when using a :belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, belongs-to

I have a :belongs_to association defined on model Brand as follows:

```
belongs_to  :loyalty_coupon, :class_name => Coupon, :foreign_key => :loyalty_coupon_id
```

(There is also a :has_many relationship from Brand to Coupon, but the :belongs_to relationship is intended to single out one particular coupon for special attention.  Relationship names and linking fields are different between the two associations, so there should be no conflict; I only mention this as it could prove relevant. The relationship is expressed as `has_many :coupons` and `belongs_to :brand`.)

When I display `Brand.first.loyalty_coupon`, I get "nil" (that's okay because I haven't assigned one yet).  When I attempt to assign a loyalty_coupon with the command `Brand.first.loyalty_coupon = Coupon.first`, I get the error message:

```
undefined method `match' for #<Class:0x104036d30>
```

with a partial traceback as follows:

```
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/base.rb:1016:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/base.rb:1180:in `compute_type'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:162:in `send'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:162:in `klass'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:173:in `build_association'
```

Same error message if I do `Brand.first.build_loyalty_coupon` (not surprising since it's doing the same thing).  I had no :has_one in the Coupon model, but I also tried that with :class_name and :foreign_key specified, and got the same error and traceback when I tried `Coupon.first.brand_loyalty`.  I imagine that I'm missing something stupid, but I can't see what it is.

Comment: You need foreign_key and class names on both sides of the relationship for the has_one :loyalty_coupon etc... Give it a try

Comment: @jamesw: Correct. This unfortunately will not fix the issue though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `:class_name` option should be a String, not a Class object. This is so that ActiveRecord does not attempt to load "class B" which may reference "class A" which would reference "class B" and so on and so forth.

```
belongs_to  :loyalty_coupon, :class_name => "Coupon"
```

`String` objects have the `match` method while `Class` objects do not.

You don't need to include the `:foreign_key` option, as it is inferred from the association's name.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple.  Thanks a lot of for the help!